# Ask a solution for AI to solve duplicate operations

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a lot of data that can train these data to achieve the results I want through some kind of AI model without connected to the Internet?At this stage, is there a kind of open source project that can be achieved. Through the logic I give, this solution with low learning costs?

For example, my data is an application question, and then this similar question appears many times in the database. When I enter a certain question, the training model will give me a formula for answering me like ChatGPT.

Specific data: x is 3, y is 4, calculate their sum.Then the training model will be formula: result =#x#+#y#.In order to push.This is a simple example.The actual input is a natural language. For example, I asked for 3 days, and for another 4 days, for a total of a few days.The formal formula result =#x#+#y#

I tried to use Chatglm to deploy to the local area, but the effect is not ideal, or the cost that may need to be learned is higher. I want more opinions and suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, there are no specifics or code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that can be done in python. Ask a question, allow user input, do the math you want to do and output your desired answer in the format that makes the most sense to the user. Hope that helps.